# Stop mouse joint from dragging current rigidBody without mouse-up?

Tags: cocos2d-x-js

I have a hero, I drag him with-mouse joint attached to his rigidBody. But I want to stop dragging him when he hits a trap.

I want the mouse-joint stop working without event "touch-end" being fired.
But I've tried to remove even the mouseJoin-Component from the hero node without luck.

Please any one with any suggestion ?

I'm using Cocos Creator with JS
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to trigger a fake event "touch-end" on the node without luck. But a minute later I found the answer (It was pretty simple)

```
node.active = false;
node.active = true;
```

When node is inactive, it stop dragging.